# RegCreateKeyEx создает ключ не там где указано

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, реестр

есть Windows 10, 64 разряда. Приложение 32 разрядное. Вот текст небольшой функции

```
    HKEY hKey;
LONG lResult;

lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                         L"Software\\testKey",
                         0,
                         NULL,
                         REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                         KEY_WRITE,
                         NULL,
                         &hKey,
                         NULL);
if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    log_error("Success! Key Created!\n");
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

ключ создается, но не в "Software\testKey", а в "Software\WOW3264Node\testKey", хотя я не ставлю маску "KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_WRITE". Какие еще телодвижения нужно сделать, ничего понять не могу, что бы писало куда нужно

Comment: Приложение надо 64 битное создавать либо отключать виртуализацию реестра.

Comment: а временно, как то  можно отключит виртуализацию программно, на время работы программы?